# Static cast disallowed for cast from child to parent

Tags: c++

In the following code, the VC++ IDE flags the static cast, saying, "Error: invalid type conversion." But I sure can't see why. I would have expected a pointer to a child was always safe to cast to a pointer to its parent. Can anyone help me understand this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void m();
};

class Parent
{

};

void Child::m()
{
    Parent* p1 = (Parent*)this;
    Parent* p2 = static_cast<Parent*>(this);
}
```

Comment: [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1e8d7cd13e10fdc)

Comment: The error you cite is not the first error you'd get for that code. What is the *first* error?

Comment: @BryanChen: only because you changed the code.

Comment: `Parent base class undefined`

Comment: dont use static cast, just do  Parent* p2 = <Parent*>(this);

Comment: @Programmer why not just `Parent *p2 = this;`? Upcasts are implicit!

Comment: @Programmer btw, I'm not sure what you meant, but it isn't legal C++ syntax.

Comment: Heh, Alf's nudge did the trick. The <I>first</I> error is not learning the language I am working in. I have done most of my OO coding in Java, where the above wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I see my question has 4 of the 5 needed votes to close it. I sure wish people voting to close a question would leave a comment with a reason as to why it should be closed, particularly when their reason is that it has been answered elsewhere. I did look.

Comment: @StevensMiller: It's not closed, it's on hold.  The banner beneath explains why people have voted to put it on hold.  If the question is edited to address those concerns, it will be reopened.

Comment: Well, fortunately, helpful folks guided me to an answer already. The banner says, "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." Which of those applies?

Comment: Still wondering which of the two reasons for putting this "on hold as off-topic" applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Alf.

The fix is to reorder it so the child class definition follows its parent:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Parent
{

};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void m();
};

void Child::m()
{
    Parent* p1 = (Parent*)this;
    Parent* p2 = static_cast<Parent*>(this);
}
```

The reason (or, "excuse," if you prefer) for my mistake is that I mostly program in Java, and haven't done enough C++ to remember my basics. The roughly comparable code in Java, below, does work.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child c = new Child();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public void m()
    {
        Parent p = this;
    }
}

class Parent
{

}
```

I appreciate the help. Kind of puzzled that I had to compile it to get the error message that really mattered. One would expect the IDE to have noticed this. Because it was flagging an error, I never even thought of compiling it. Will remember that for the future.

Cheers!

Comment: In case you're wondering why the IDE flagged the error the way it did,  because `Parent` wasn't defined yet it wasn't considered a parent of `Child` so the cast was invalid.

Comment: @StevensMiller the `static_cast<Parent *>(this)` is superfluous. Upcasts are free: `Parent *p2 = this;`

Comment: Yeah, I expect that's why the first cast wasn't flagged. I was more interested in why it was flagged than in actually using that line of code for anything practical.

Comment: The reason the first cast wasn't flagged is because it's an old-style C cast. Those are extremely powerful and dangerous, since they let you cast any pointer to any other pointer whether the types are related or not.